# How to prevent OPTIONS requests in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So far I have tried adding the following to my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <add verb="OPTIONS" path="*" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

You can see that I have added an entry to the `httpHandlers` node, but there were already several other entries in there so it isn't the only thing in there.

Even with both of these entries when I make the following CURL request:

```
curl -v -X OPTIONS https://mySite.com
```

I'm seeing the following in the output:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store
< Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
```

Why are `OPTIONS` requests still being allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`<authorization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.71).aspx) you can only play with verbs mapped to ASP.NET.

```
verbs: A comma-separated list of HTTP transmission methods that are denied access to the resource. Verbs registered to ASP.NET are GET, HEAD, POST, and DEBUG.
```

You could try the [`<verbs>`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs) element